# MySQL 1265 Data truncated for column - message makes no sense

Tags: mysql

I'm not clear on why I am getting this error when running a procedure that is doing a calculation (using a function) on decimal values.

I have table, stop_locations, the two relevant columns being:

```
stop_distance DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL,
stop_bearing DECIMAL(16,13) NOT NULL,
```

The two functions, and the value they return are:

```
CREATE FUNCTION distance ( lat1 DECIMAL(16,13), lon1 DECIMAL(16,13), lat2 DECIMAL(16,13), lon2 DECIMAL(16,13) )
RETURNS DECIMAL(8,4)
...

CREATE FUNCTION bearing180 ( lat1 DECIMAL(16,13), lon1 DECIMAL(16,13), lat2 DECIMAL(16,13), lon2 DECIMAL(16,13) )
RETURNS DECIMAL(16,13)
```

And finally, the procedure that produces the result I want (i.e. it works), but also produces the error:

```
1265 Data truncated for column 'stop_distance' at X
```

and the same for the `stop_bearing` column:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateLocations()
BEGIN
DECLARE lat1 DECIMAL(16,13);
DECLARE lon1 DECIMAL(16,13);

SELECT current_lat, current_lon INTO lat1, lon1 FROM current_location WHERE id = 1;

TRUNCATE TABLE stop_locations;

INSERT INTO stop_locations(stop_id, stop_distance, stop_bearing)
SELECT 
    stop_id, 
    DISTANCE(lat1, lon1, stop_lat, stop_lon) AS stop_distance,
    BEARING180(lat1, lon1, stop_lat, stop_lon) AS stop_bearing
FROM 
    stops;    
END
```

So, if the functions **distance** and **bearing180** are returning **DECIMAL(8,4)** and **DECIMAL(16,13)** respectively, and the table columns match that, what is being truncated, why the message?

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: What is the definition of stop_id in the 2 tables?

Comment: both tables:   stop_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL